# Change voltage range

Tags: voltage

I have a hall sensor AH49E and an ESP32 S3. The sensor's output voltage in my case ranges from 1.5V to 2.1V, which gives me only a 0.6V range. How can I change the voltage range to 0 - 3.3V?

Comment: I guess the sensor don't have that output, so you need to amplify the signal. You need a binary or analog signal? || Since you wrote *range* you want an analog signal, then an opamp is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you require voltage gain, you'll need an op-amp, and since most op-amps cannot output voltages very near their own power supply potentials, then unless you have a negative supply for your op-amp, and a positive supply that exceeds 3.3V, you should aim for a slightly smaller output voltage range.

By doing this, the signal reaching the microcontroller will not have the full 0-3.3 volt range, but rather something more like 0.1V to 3.2V. That means you lose a small percentage of the entire ADC conversion range, and will need compensation in software for the zero-offset, to obtain the true voltage reading, but this is small price to pay compared to having to build special voltage sources for the op-amp.

Here's a circuit that will output between 0.1V and 3.2V, corresponding to an input that goes between 1.5V and 2.1V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffVg80.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Read on to find out how I designed that circuit.

Step one is to calculate the gain. Input and output ranges are respectively \$(+2.1V) - (+1.5V) = +0.6V\$ and \$(+3.2V) - (+0.1V) = +3.1V\$. This corresponds to a gain \$A\$ of:

$$ A = \frac{3.1V}{0.6V} = 5.17 $$

Just multiplying the input by 5.17 isn't enough. We also need to offset the signal. We require that when the input is at +1.5V, the output should then be +0.1V. In other words:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= A \times V_{IN} + V_{OFS} \\ \\
0.1 &= 5.17 \times 1.5 + V_{OFS}  \\ \\
V_{OFS} &= 0.1 - 5.17 \times 1.5 \\ \\
&= -7.66 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So, this is the relationship between output and input that we are aiming for:

$$ V_{OUT} =  V_{IN} \times 5.17 + (-7.66) $$

A circuit that can do that might look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGeJLW.png)</sup>

This circuit has the following output/input relationship:

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{IN}\overbrace{\left(1+\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)}^{Gain} + \overbrace{\left(-V_X\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)}^{Offset} $$

As you can see, there are terms easily recognisable as corresponding to the gain and offset terms in the desired relationship:

$$ V_{OUT} =  V_{IN} \times \overbrace{5.17}^{Gain} + \overbrace{(-7.66)}^{Offset} $$

By equating the respective terms we obtain two simultaneous equations which can be solved to reveal the required values, \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$V_X\$. With only two equations, and three unknowns, we are required to "guess" one of the unknowns, by setting it to a sensible value. I will set \$R_2 = 10k\Omega\$, as that will simplify the solution:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2}\right) &= 5.17 \\ \\
\frac{R_1}{R_2} &= 5.17 - 1 \\ \\
R_1 &= 4.17 \times R_2 \\ \\
&= 41.7k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The second (offset) equation can reveal \$V_X\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
-V_X\frac{R_1}{R_2} &= -7.66 \\ \\
V_X &= 7.66\frac{10k}{41.7k} \\ \\
&= 1.84V
\end{aligned}
$$

\$V_X\$ is provided by voltage source V1 in the above circuit, so now we have  all the information needed to simulate these results, and verify that the output indeed behaves as we predict:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEw1bB.png)</sup>

If I sweep V2 (the source of input potential \$V_{IN}\$) from 1.4V to 2.2V, this is the corresponding \$V_{OUT}\$:

[image]

This is working so far, but we're not done yet. We don't have a voltage source of 1.84V. To produce one, we'll use a resistor potential divider across the 3.3V power supply, and we'll use [Thevenin's theorem](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/) to replace R2 and V1 with our new divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuiL1h.png)</sup>

This conversion requires that Q (unloaded) be at 1.84V, and that the parallel combination of R3 and R4 be equal to R2. This gives us two more simultaneous equations to solve:

$$
\begin{aligned}
3.3 \frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4} &= 1.84 \\ \\
\frac{R_3 \times R_4}{R_3 + R_4} &= 10k \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I won't show my working here, but these are the values I calculated for R3 and R4:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_3 = 17.9k\Omega \\ \\
R_4 = 22.6k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The last thing to do is find an op-amp that will operate from a 3.3V supply, and has rail-to-rail output capability, so that is actually able to produce from +0.1V to +3.2V at its output. A [TLC2272](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2272.pdf) fits the bill. These values for R3 and R4, and the model TLC2272 are the components you see in the very first circuit in this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've created a simple page for calculations.
https://jsfiddle.net/TomasChladek/gaopj60w/

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why do you need the 0V..3.3V range?

The ESP32 S3 has a 12bit SAR A/D converter which provides a resolution of 0.24 mV/V. So you could measure (edit!) **744** distinct voltages within the 0.6V output range of the AH49E.

If you really need to boost this sensor output to 0-3.3V, you could use a differential amplifier with a gain setting of 5.5. But you would need to connect one input of the diff. amp. to a reference providing the AH49E zero-field voltage of approximately Vcc/2. And you would need to tune that for every circuit.

Comment: With a couple of bits of noise (a guess without looking at the datasheet, but a sensible working assumption to start optimising from for many ADCs) the number of available values doesn't look so good after all.